# What does this expression means about a person ? 「……やけに他人事だな、貴様は」

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**Context**: A clan leader wanted to keep MC in her family/clan because she thinks MC is a skilled warrior and can use him. But her subordinate disagreed and wanted to kick MC out, since she's worried that MC could cause harm to her leader. Also this world where MC has been isekai'd to, is in chaos where war happens everywhere, so the subordinate suggested that her clan leader should be very careful to an unknow stranger like MC.

Hope someone an explain to me the correct meaning of this sentence 「……やけに他人事だな、貴様は」(i can only guess but not sure: "...You're really like to worries about someone else's business, aren't you ?" )

More context:

> Clan leader「結菜。おまえはどうだ？」
>
> Subordinate「……私はまだ反対。この者の真意が見えないわ。取り入った後、隙を見つけて悪事を働くことも考えられる」
>
> Subordinate「母、道三が美濃でやったように、この下克上の時代、不明の者を側に置くには、細心の注意を払った方がいい」
>
> MC「全くもってその通りだね」
>
> **Clan leader「……やけに他人事だな、貴様は」**
>
> MC「だって俺がそっちのみんなと同じ立場なら、同じ心配をしてると思うし。……なぁ、やっぱり俺、出て行った方がいいんじゃない？」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means (貴様の発言は)まるで他人事のようだな, or "(Your comment) sounds as if it's (about) someone else's problem (although it actually is not)". Here, MC is saying he himself should be suspected and refused, almost like he isn't interested in defending his own position. The leader pointed out such a behavior is unusual.

So, interestingly, although the literal meaning of this 他人事だな is "It's someone else's problem", its actual implication here is "It's *your* problem". 他人事 is commonly used as part of (実際には他人事ではないのに)まるで他人事のようだ, so just saying 他人事だな can have the same implication.